# Inequality with pi

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

> Prove that, for any sequences of real numbers $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$, we have
>   $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_mb_n}{m+n}\le \pi\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_m^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n^2\right)^{1/2} $$

How can I solve this problem? I've got no idea for it... Please help!

Comment: **Hint:** $\displaystyle\pi=\sqrt6\cdot\bigg[\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\bigg]^{1/2}-$ See [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) for more information. Then use the [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product), along with some inequalities related to quadratic and geometric means.

Comment: Would you clarify the usage of those things? It's seems awkward :(

Answer (score 1):

By using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in the following form:
$$\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_mb_n}{m+n} \right)^2\le \left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_m^2}{m+n}\sqrt{\frac{m}n} \right) \left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{b_n^2}{m+n}\sqrt{\frac{n}m} \right) \tag {$\star$}$$

for the first factor on the RHS, we have
$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_m^2}{m+n}\sqrt{\frac{m}n} = \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_m^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{m/n}}{m+n}$$

Further we have 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{m/n}}{m+n} \le \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{m/x}}{m+x}dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{\sqrt t \;(1+t)} = \pi$$
where we have used $x = mt$ as a substitution.  By symmetry the second factor in the RHS of $\star$ also can be treated similarly, giving you the result.